# Move HTML variable through views to python script in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

While working in Django I am trying to take a variable from HTML input, pass it to views.py for some decision making, then pass it from views.py to a separate python script in my project.

Here is my upload form in my HTML file, this step works fine:

```
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'upload' %}">
              {% csrf_token %}  
              <input type='file' name='document' accept='.csv' required><br>
              <label for='axis'>Which column is the x-axis?<label>
              <input type='number' name='axis' id='axis' required><br>
              <button type='submit' name='csvreader'>Bar Graph</button>
              <button type='submit' name='line_plot'>Line Graph</button>
              <button type='submit' name='scatter_plot'>Scatter Plot</button>
            </form>
```

Then in my views.py, I use it to check if the value is valid before calling the python script, also works fine:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST.get, request.FILES)
        file=request.FILES['document']
        df = pd.read_csv(file,header=None)
        data = pd.DataFrame(df)
        length = len(data.columns)
        item = Item()
        item.text = request.POST.get('axis', '')
        item.save()
        request.session['item.text'] = item.text
        if ((int(item.text) < 0)) | ((int(item.text) >= length)):
            HttpResponse("Your axis is not valid")
        if 'csvreader' in request.POST:
            csv = CSV.objects.create(doc=file)
            os.system('python csvreader2.py')
        if 'line_plot' in request.POST:
            csv = CSV.objects.create(doc=file)
            os.system('python line_plot.py')
        if 'scatter_plot' in request.POST:
            csv = CSV.objects.create(doc=file)
            os.system('python scatter_plot.py')
        return render(request, 'uploaded.html')
```

And finally, I want to use it to define which line of the csv file will be the x axis, this is my issue. I have no idea how to reference the variable in either the html page or views.py from here.

```
#Asks user which column they would like to use for x axis labels and takes it from the csv file
x_lab = 0
col_1= list(df[int(x_lab)])
col_1.pop(0)
done = 0
x_value = []
x_val = 0
count = 1
```

I'm not using Flask or Ajax for this project(assignment constraints), so I don't know how to reference this variable in my python script. I attempted reworking csvreader.py into a view of its own for easy movement, but then I kept getting error: 'main thread is not in main loop', so I assume I can't just have the python file become its own view.

Answer (score 0):

If your python script takes an input and returns something, even if only a success indicator, make your code into a function and import it for your views:

In csvreader2.py

```
def create_graph(axis)
    ...#do work
    return True
```

Place your csvreader2.py in your django directory at the same level as views (or wherever else it makes sense for you)

In views.py

```
from .csvreader2 import create_graph

def upload(request):
   ...#do work
   success = create_graph(item.text)
   ...
   #pass  axis to your template as a context values
   if success:
       return render(request, 'uploaded.html', {"axis": item.text})
```

Comment: This seems like a step in the right direction, althoug I had to change backends to avoid getting "main thread is not in main loop" errors, and now its taking up a ton of memory and not completing sometimes. I don't need to pass axis onto uploaded.html, I just need it to act as a value in csvreader.

Comment: The main loop issue is likely quite separate from the passing values question, and might need its own question focussing on how django is integrating with whatever has the main loop (tkinter?)